# javascript fetch an image and create base64

Tags: javascript, base64, service-worker, cloudflare

I'm using CloudFlare service workers and I want to fetch an image and then generate a base64 representation of it.

So something like this:

```
const res = await fetch('https://cdn.cnn.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/211010073527-tyson-fury-exlarge-169.jpg')
  const blob = await res.blob();
  
  console.log(blob)
  console.log(btoa(blob))
```

this of course doesn't work, any ideas how to get this resolved?

Comment: btoa works with binary, check [here](https://javascript.info/blob#blob-to-base64) how you can transform blob to base64

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need a base64 version of that file? Encoding binary files to Base64 should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: I need to respond with a vcard file, and it has a base64 encoded image for the contact image. would be happy to hear other ideas. using this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcards-js

Comment: They have an [`attachFromURL`](https://github.com/enesser/vCards-js/blob/99a298c72d3cf31741eaa39e9c66df973e9fec91/index.js#L25) method, why can't you just use that?

Comment: @Kaiido it uses the "fs" module and it doesn't exist in Cloudflare service workers

Comment: Do they? I see that they do indeed use `fs` to grab the data when using `embedFromFile()`, but `attachFromURL` seems to really just attach the URL, not even fetching it or anything. Then I guess it will be the client's responsibility to fetch it when displaying the V-Card (though I'm not an expert in VCards).

Comment: it may be an option to have a url in the vcard, but I prefer to have the vcard full and not require a download from the web as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

complete worker script with `cloudflare` using [**btoa**](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/web-standards/#web-global-apis)

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

const imageUrl =
  'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/72/' +
  'Cat_playing_with_a_lizard.jpg/1200px-Cat_playing_with_a_lizard.jpg';

function base64Encode (buf) {
  let string = '';
  (new Uint8Array(buf)).forEach(
      (byte) => { string += String.fromCharCode(byte) }
    )
  return btoa(string)
}

function base64Decode (string) {
  string = atob(string);
  const
    length = string.length,
    buf = new ArrayBuffer(length),
    bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) { bufView[i] = string.charCodeAt(i) }
  return buf
}

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const
    upstreamResponse = await fetch(imageUrl),
    text = base64Encode(await upstreamResponse.arrayBuffer()),
    bin = base64Decode(text);
  
  return new Response(bin, {status: 200, headers: {
      'Content-type': upstreamResponse.headers.get('Content-type')
    }})
}
```

can refer this [discussion](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/convert-request-body-to-base64-encoded-string-solved/99341/6) as well

Comment: the problem is I dont have access to FileReader in cloudflare service worker

Comment: then you  can use cloudfare **btoa** and can convert it in bytes using arrayBuffer

Comment: checkout updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
async function getBase64FromUrl(url: string): Promise<string> {
    const data = await fetch(url);
    const blob = await data.blob();

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
        reader.onerror = (err) => reject(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).